# RequireJS Optimization and the text plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I'm using the RequireJS optimizer to optimize modules that also use the text plugin.  In order to not have the text! plugin loaded over and over again with each optimized module, I do this

```
node r.js -o stubModules=text name=Main out=main-master-built.js
```

Which works, producing in part the following

```
define("text",{load:function(e){throw new Error("Dynamic load not allowed: "+e)}})
define("text!f.htm",[],function(){return"<h3>Hello World</h3>\r\n<h4>Bam</h4>"})
```

Unfortunately, as the above shows, I can no longer use the text plugin "normally."  The error-throwing stub above prevents me from adding a text! call to an un-optimized dependency list.

Is there any way around this?  Is there any option I can put in that would, say, change these `text` references on the fly to `texto` and then do something like

```
define("texto",{load:function(e){throw new Error("Dynamic load not allowed: "+e)}})
define("texto!f.htm",[],function(){return"<h3>Hello World</h3>\r\n<h4>Bam</h4>"})
```

Or some other option that will optimize modules with text dependencies while not also killing my ability to keep using it dynamically?

Comment: Did you try just not stubbing the `text` plugin. I'd expect that if you load anything which is defined with a name (e.g. `define("text!f.htm", ...)`), it would load without using the plugin. Then anything which does *not* have a named define (has not been optimized) would use the `text` plugin.

Comment: If I don't stub the text plugin, then the entire text plugin is loaded and dumped right into the optimized file :(

Comment: If you want to use `text!` to load text fragments that have not gone though the optimization process then you need to have the plugin available *somewhere*.

Comment: Well, sure.  But when the app runs, then `text` **will** already exist.  Is there no way to bake that knowledge into the optimizer?  Or maybe even do an on-the-fly renaming of it to something else, say `textopt` just for the purpose of the optimized file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the deal. If everything loaded through `text!` has been optimized with `r.js`, then all text has been included in the output of `r.js`, and you can stub the plugin.

However, if you want to have the ability to use `text!` to load text that has *not* been through the optimization process, then you must have the `text!` plugin available at run time. In this case you cannot stub it, otherwise RequireJS won't be able to load the text pieces that you have not optimized because there won't be a `text!` plugin for RequireJS to use.

In an application that contains modules loaded by `text!` that have been optimized and modules loaded by `text!` that have not been optimized, the following will happen:

- For a module that *has* been optimized, RequireJS will find a `define` call with module's name (because this is part of what `r.js` does). For instance, `define("text!foo", [...], function(...)`. In a case like this, RequireJS will not try to use the `text!` plugin to load this module. It will just load the module directly. (This *has* to be true otherwise stubbing the `text!` plugin would cause RequireJS to fail as soon as any optimized module that uses `text!` is required.)
- For a module that has *not* been optimized, RequireJS will ask `text!` to load the module.

Unless special measures are taken, `r.js` automatically includes the entire `text!` plugin when it finds it among the dependencies of a bundle of modules.

So to exclude the text module specifically, use the `excludeShallow` option.  Your new command line/bat file would look something like this:

```
node r.js -o name=Main excludeShallow=text out=main-master-built-text-path.js
```

Comment: So I think it boils down to what the special measures are that can be taken to not have r.js include the entire `text!` plugin when it finds it among the dependencies of a bundle of modules.  Obviously stubbing is not an option.  Is it possible to omit the `text!` **plugin**, but still load the `text!foo` ?

Comment: It is possible to omit the plugin and still load `text!foo`, provided that `text!foo` has been optimized by `r.js`, and you do not try to load non-optimized modules with `text!`.

Comment: excludeShallow - that's what I wanted.  I hope you don't mind me editing it into your answer and upvoting/accepting.  You really explained everything else quite well.

Comment: The edit is fine. I'm still not getting why you want to exclude the `text!` specifically since your use-case is to "use the text module normally" so you have to have it... or is it that you want to be able to use it *before* your optimized bundle is loaded by RequireJS? (In the typical use scenarios documented on the RequireJS site the optimized bundle is the entry point to the whole application.)

Comment: I'll have a bunch of these optimized file around.  I don't want text.js copied each and every time.